# Query about fetching popular articles from WordPress using the rest API?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a test flutter assignment. I want to fetch popular articles from WordPress using REST API!

I have two files for it. **popular_articles_page.dart** and **popular_articles_bloc.dart**

**popular_articles_page.dart looks like this:**

```
  List<Article> _articles = [];
  bool? _hasData;
  var scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final String _timeRange = 'last7days';
  final int _postLimit = 50;
```

**popular_articles_bloc.dart  looks like this:**

```
  int _contentAmount = 4;
  final String _timeRange = 'last7days';
```

Now the question is, when I change the "**final String _timeRange = 'last7days';**" in **popular_articles_bloc.dart**, the popular post timeframe is adjusted according to it. (for example, **last7days** - fetch last week's popular articles).

But when I change the "**final String _timeRange = 'last30days';**" in **popular_articles_page.dart**,  nothing happens!

I want to figure out what popular_articles_page.dart is doing here If it's not necessary?

Comment: Is the page sending the time range to the bloc, or do you have a hardcoded value in your bloc and you're expecting a variable change in the page to somehow affect it?

Comment: I don't know how these two files are linked. That's what I am trying to understand. Here is the popular_articles_bloc.dart file: https://pastebin.com/rZkkaaAm, and here is the popular_articles_page.dart file: https://pastebin.com/9tMyuF6Y. Can you Please look into it and let me know how it's working?

Comment: It doesn't look like the page uses the bloc file at all.

Comment: When I edit the bloc.dart's "final String _timeRange ='last7days'; (line 15)", the changes are reflected in the app, but when I try to edit anything on the page.dart file, it won't work.